# Two customs attributes, only one is saved in the database

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes

I added two custom attributes in the order and quote table.

One is `delivery_date` : the delivery timeslot chosen by the user.
The other is `additionnal_information`

The two rows are created but only one of them (delivery_date) is filled when an order is submitted. The other is `NULL`

If I try this in the observer : `mage::log($order->getAdditionnalInformation())`, it returns something

Does someone knows why ?

My install script :

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->addAttribute("order", "delivery_date", array("type"=>"varchar"));
$installer->addAttribute("quote", "delivery_date", array("type"=>"varchar"));
$installer->addAttribute("order", "additionnal_information", array("type"=>"varchar"));
$installer->addAttribute("quote", "additionnal_information", array("type"=>"varchar"));
$installer->endSetup();
```

My config file (only the global part) :

```
<global>
    <events>
        <sales_quote_save_before>
            <observers>
                <save_before>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>CoursierPrive_Transport_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>saveQuoteBefore</method>
                </save_before>
            </observers>
        </sales_quote_save_before>
        <checkout_type_onepage_save_order>
            <observers>
                <delivery_date_observer>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>CoursierPrive_Transport_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>saveCustomData</method>
                </delivery_date_observer>
            </observers>
        </checkout_type_onepage_save_order>
    </events>
    <fieldsets>
        <sales_convert_quote>
            <delivery_date>
                <to_order>*</to_order>
            </delivery_date>
            <additionnal_information>
                <to_order>*</to_order>
            </additionnal_information>
        </sales_convert_quote>
        <sales_convert_order>
            <delivery_date>
                <to_quote>*</to_quote>
            </delivery_date>
            <additionnal_information>
                <to_quote>*</to_quote>
            </additionnal_information>
        </sales_convert_order>
    </fieldsets>
     <resources>
        <transport_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>CoursierPrive_Transport</module>
                <class>Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
            </setup>
        </transport_setup>
    </resources>
</global>
```

And my observer :

```
<?php
class CoursierPrive_Transport_Model_Observer
{
    public function saveCustomData($observer)
    {
        $event = $observer->getEvent();
        $order = $event->getOrder();
        $timestamp = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getData('delivery_date');
        $additionnalInformation = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getData('additionnal_information');
        $order->setAdditionnalInformation($additionnalInformation);
        $order->setDeliveryDate($timestamp);
    }

    public function saveQuoteBefore($observer)
    {
        $post = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getPost();

        if(isset($post['field']['delivery_date']))
        {
            $var = $post['field']['delivery_date'];
            Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setData('delivery_date', $var);
        }
        if(isset($post['field']['additionnal_information']))
        {
            $var = $post['field']['additionnal_information'];
            Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setData('additionnal_information', $var);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: did you clear the cache?

Comment: Caches are disabled.

Comment: Please delete the cache. even if it's disabled, the table schema is still cached.

Comment: Oh you were right. Deleting the cache resolved my problem. Thanks you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments.
The table schema is cached even if the cache is off.
Deleting the cache should solve the problem.